# What language is 'chr' and why is my homepage set there?

Tags: google-search, firefox

For reasons I can't fathom, my Google searches keep ending up at `http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=chr`.

What language is 'chr' (I don't know why I can't find this by searching Google, but I can't)?

More importantly, how do I stop it?

(Note: going to 'settings' and setting my language to 'English' was not effective.)

Edit: It's a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=580833) in Firefox.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a Firebox bug caused the issue, as it was noted in the question. It's already fixed and it's 13 years old.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whoa, those are crazy letters! I think Alex is right about the Cherokee language.

Use [google.com/**ncr**](http://google.com/ncr) to force the English interface. ("ncr" means "No Country/Culture Redirect.")

If you want to force your browser's homepage to show Google in English, you will have to set your homepage to [google.com/ncr](http://google.com/ncr) in your browser's settings.

**Edit:** Google probably determines which default UI language to show based on your IP address. Your IP address probably geo-locates to a place where Cherokee is used by most of the people. For example, I am located in Korea, and I always get the Korean version of Google. However, if I set the Google settings to use the English UI, it uses English for that computer/browser. This requires browser cookies; do you have cookies enabled?

Also, if your browser explicitly sets your homepage to http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=chr then Google will dutifully display Cherokee.

Comment: The *redirect* fix is unsatisfactory. Why does it keep redirecting me there? I've changed Google's settings to english. Changing the browser to use google.com/ncr (it just uses Google) is a nasty nasty fix for the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is no place where Cherokee is used by most of the people. The geo-location theory must be incorrect.

Comment: Browsers usually have a list of preferred languages. Google considers both that and the IP geolocation, or at least it did use each of them at various points in history.

Answer (score 13):

I had this too, and discovered this in my Firefox language settings:

[image]

Firefox must be seeing "chrome" and reading "chr" = cherokee. Removing that line fixed the problem.

I've recently turned on Firefox sync, Xmarks (installed in both Firefox and Chrome) and Chrome sync, so I suspect one of them has done this by mistake. Funny!

Comment: I use firefox sync, so that might be the culprit.

Comment: Yes, I think you must be right - Firefox sync is trying to sync the language preferences. But where is it getting 'chrome...properties' from?

Comment: Yes Tim!

The Chrome thing was the problem. I guess the problem was using Xmarks with all browsers together at first, then switching to FireFox Sync. The FireFox Sync add-on saves and misinterprets the Google Chrome settings leading to this funny problem.

Another question: did you all use Windows or Linux based platforms? I got this problem just with Ubuntu.

Cheers
Frank

Comment: Well, chrome is the name for files and resources within firefox, but I don't know how it got like that.

Comment: See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=580833 for the bug report.

Comment: I had the same problem using namoroka (ie firefox 3.6) with Ubuntu 10.10. I also used xmarks previously, then switched to firefox sync). Minefield (ie firefox 4 beta) and chromium are also installed, for info.

Answer (score 5):

It's the Cherokee language & alphabet:
http://www.native-languages.org/cherokee_alphabet.htm

Answer (score -2):

Just follow this detailed tutorial on [making Google your Homepage](http://a-zblogger.com/make-google-my-homepage/) .If it doesn't work replace google.com with google.com/ncr ,that must work.

Comment: That suggestion was already given by the answer, marked as accepted.